# Why can't I view Stackdriver logs for Web Apps in Google Apps Script?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm working on a project in Google Script, but the Stackdriver logging is giving me some issues. When I run a script from the project, I can view the execution list and click on an execution to "expand" it and display the logs, such as error messages. However, if the script is run as a web app, for example calling a post request, I'm not able to view the logs. Clicking on the execution does nothing. This is an issue because I can't see any error messages, just that the execution failed. 
[image: Cannot click on these executions, & thus cannot see the logs]
[image: Any time I run the script from the editor I can view the logs]

Comment: I don't know *why*, so this isn't an answer. I've faced your issue and it is very annoying. You need to switch to a [GCP Project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) so that you can use [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) instead. Then you'll be able to see everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Basic logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging) doesn't support Web Apps' executions logs, only the info for each execution but not their logs. To see those kind of logs you need to use [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) in cloud.google.com, for this you need to follow these steps:

1) Create a [Google Cloud project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project).

2) Link the script to the project going to ["Resources"->"Cloud Platform project"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#accessing_a_standard_gcp_project).

3) See the logs going to ["View"->"Stackdriver Logging"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#viewing_stackdriver_logs_and_error_reports_in_the_google_cloud_platform_console).

Comment: This no longer works, I tried linking it to a new google cloud project and it would just give "Project does not exist or you need edit access to it.